# Swift: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '@noescape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, ios9

I know this is a simple question, yet i am having problem finding the solutions.

In Swift 2.2, I am getting this error.

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
>   '@noescape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool'

Here is the code.

```
var tableDataSectionsDict: CHOrderedDictionary?
if !tableDataSectionsDict!.allKeys.contains("Yesterday") {
   tableDataSectionsDict!.insertObject(YesterdayArray, forKey: "Yesterday", atIndex: count)
}
```

[image]

What i am missing here ? Can anybody shade some light on it ?

Comment: Look at definition of `contains` function. It expects closure, not a String.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz There are 2 `contains` functions; one expects a closure, and one expects an element.  It looks like this is a dictionary of `AnyObject`s, so the type inference might be getting confused when passed a string.

Comment: OP uses `CHOrderedDictionary`. Maybe it has only 1 `contains` function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that `CHOrderedDictionary` is [this CHOrderedDictionary](https://github.com/quinntaylor/CHDataStructures/blob/master/source/CHOrderedDictionary.m). If that's the case, it is an Objective-C type that you have bridged to Swift (please correct me if I'm wrong).

There are two `contains` functions available:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Returns `true` iff `element` is in `self`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}

extension SequenceType {
    /// Returns `true` iff an element in `self` satisfies `predicate`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func contains(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
}
```

`CHOrderedDictionary`'s keys and values are converted from `id` in Objective-C to `AnyObject` in Swift. `AnyObject` does not conform to `Equatable`, so you cannot use the first `contains` function. You could proabably write a wrapper around `CHOrderedDictionary` to allow some `Equatable` element types if you really wanted to.

The fastest solution here will be to use the more generic version of `contains` (the second `contains`). In code, it would look something like this:

```
// contains will iterate over the entire allKeys array. $0 is the key at each iteration.
let containsKey = tableDataSectionsDict!.allKeys.contains { return $0 as? String == "Yesterday" }
if !containsKey {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using a bridging header for this CHOrderedDictionary Objective-C Class.

And thanks for the code example. That worked perfectly.